# button click won't fire

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
        <div id="div1">Click here</div>
    </div>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var $ = function(e) { return document.getElementById(e); };
        var pageDefault = {
            btn1: $('Button1'),

            testfx: function() {
                alert('test');
            },

            init: function() {
                this.btn1.onclick = function() {
                    this.testfx();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        pageDefault.init();
    </script>
</body>
```

Why won't button1 click event fire?

Comment: why the - 1? to the op question?

Comment: @Mr. Dunno.. +1 to fight that nonsense off. @rod check out Li0liQ's answer. You need to use the ClientID of the asp.net control. The rendered markup will not have the `Button1` ID, so your selector won't work.

Comment: in this case it works, it has the same id. in others situations it may change, it would be a good practice, but in this one, works as it, the primary problem is the `this.testfx()`

Comment: @Mr I guess the definition of "not firing event" could be different. However, if wrong `this` is the case, the event should have already been fired and handled, because otherwise `onclick` handler's code will not even be executed... and we'll get yet another javascript exception.

Comment: @Li0liQ you are right, the event was fired, but not executed the alert that he wanted to.

Comment: @Mr. Only in case `asp.net` hasn't tangled the ids;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may happen that you need to use `$('<%= Button1.ClientID %>')` instead of `$('Button1')`.
See [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/asptest/archive/2009/01/06/asp-net-4-0-clientid-overview.aspx) article for more details.

Another issue, mentioned in other answers, is that event handler refers to `this` which is `window`. To fix that you could rewrite your handler in the following manner:

```
this.btn1.onclick = function() {
    pageDefault.testfx();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Definitely this. Clientside markup for .net is going to have different IDs than the rendered content. ClientID must be used as you said. +1.

Comment: why wouldn't it be pageDefault.btn1.onclick as well then?

Comment: @rod Fortunately, by invoking `pageDefault.init()` you are running `init` method in the context of `pageDefault`, hence `this.btn1.onclick` equals to `pageDefault.btn1.onclick`. But the `onclick` handler will be executed in the context of `window` by default.

Comment: I may have to accept your answer and say it kinda makes sense, but you got anything else below layman's terms?, if not, I would understand as well :)

Comment: @rod As already mentioned, there are two issues with that code:
1. `asp.net` may or may not(depends on the version you use) generate unique id for its elements while rendering the page(you could check that by viewing source of the generated page) - resolved by asking asp.net to provide generated id, `ClientID ` property of the control, where needed.
2. event handler is invoked in the context of `window` by default - resolved by not using `this` in the handler.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is not in the same scope in that part of the code.

Try this

```
init: function() {
that = this // create's a that variable which refers to the current scope
this.btn1.onclick = function() {
    that.testfx(); // this now points to the scope of pageDefault
    // Same as doing pageDefault.testfx();
    return false;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rhkct/)

Answer (score 0):

Because the `this` in  `this.testfx();`  is not the `pageDefault.testfx()` is `Button1.testfx()`

it should be

```
this.btn1.onclick = function() {
    pageDefault.testfx();
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think because btn1 is a jquery object.so use this instade:

```
init: function() {
                this.btn1.click(function() {
                    this.testfx();
                    return false;
                });
            }
```